# The "> (tee -a ...)" command in Bash

Tags: bash, unix, tee

I have this Bash code that runs [Scala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29) test code:

```
scripts=(
Hello.scala
)

for script in "${scripts[@]}"; do
    echo scala "${script}"
    scala -nocompdaemon "${script}" > >(tee -a _testoutput.txt) \
        2> >(tee -a _testerrors.txt >&2)
done
```

How can I interpret `>(tee -a _testoutput.txt)`? I normally use `|` (pipe) for using [tee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)). What's the difference when using this expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case I believe `> >(tee -a _testoutput.txt)` and `| tee -a _testoutput.txt` would behave identically.

The [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)) version of that is obviously necessary since there is no standard error pipe.

The other main difference between the pipe version and the *[process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution)* (`>(...)`) version is where the subshell happens.

If, for example, the `>(...)` were on the entire loop and you needed variables set in the loop to persist outside of the loop you couldn't do that with the pipe version (see [Bash FAQ 24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) for more about this).

One additional difference, correctly [pointed out by Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28992111/tee-a-command-in-bash#comment46235007_28992201), is that a pipe affects the exit status of the pipeline (by default you get the exit status of the final command in the pipeline though `set -o pipefail` changes that and the Bash `PIPESTATUS` array holds all of the exit statuses). Process substitution, on the other hand, doesn't affect the exit status.

Comment: The other difference is exit status; `> >(tee -a foo)` doesn't change exit status, whereas `| tee -a foo` does.

Comment: Using a process substitution can have some caveats: if the process substituted finishes early and the main process still wants to write some stuff, then it's the main process that will receive SIGPIPE: `{ sleep 1; echo a; } > >(:)`.

Answer (score 3):

`>( list )` is called "process substitution". It's more powerful than a normal pipe: You can't use `|` to redirect standard output and standard error to different programs so easily.

Comment: You _can_ use pipes to redirect stdout and stderr to different programs, using appropriate redirections. It's a bit ugly, but doable without any major caveats.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: True, with `2>&7` and stuff, you can. Updated.